# Handle and stop close event of dynamically created Part with Part Descriptor

Tags: java, swt, rcp

I have a Part Descriptor that is closeable and create a Part from it in a handler.

```
final MPart part = partService.createPart("workbench.partdescriptor.session");
partService.showPart(part, PartState.ACTIVATE);
```

Now I want to handle close events(when hitting the cross on the tab), so I add a Listener to the Composite in my @PostContruct annotated method.

Inside this handler the user should be prompted to confirm whether to actually close the part.

```
@PostConstruct
public void createPartControl(final Composite parent) {
    parent.addListener(SWT.Close,
            event -> event.doit = MessageDialog.openConfirm(parent.getShell(), "Confirm", "Really?"));
    // UI stuff
}
```

But the listener is never called. Also the Composite is of the type ContributedPartRenderer if that helps.

What i also tried is using @PreDestroy and a disposeListener, but it is not applicable, since the Part is already disposed in both cases.

I even tried to add an CTabFolderListener to the parent of the Composite since its a CTabFolder, but again the Composite is already disposed when the listener is called.

```
((CTabFolder)parent.getParent()).addCTabFolder2Listener(new CTabFolder2Adapter() {
    @Override
    public void close(final CTabFolderEvent event) {
        event.doit = MessageDialog.openConfirm(duTabFolderParent.getShell(), "Confirm", "Really?");
    }
});
```

So how can I handle the closing of the Part and stop the part from actually closing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to do this is mark the part as dirty when you want to be prompted about saving. To mark the part as dirty call the MPart.setDirty(true) method.

You can then install an implementation of `ISaveHandler` in your main window context. This has methods that will be called to prompt for saving and saving the dirty parts.

You can do this in the application startup complete event (probably in your life cycle class).

```
@Optional
@Inject
public void appStartupComplete(@UIEventTopic(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE) org.osgi.service.event.Event event, 
                               MApplication app, EModelService modelService)
{
  // Find top level window

  MWindow window = (MWindow)modelService.find("main window id", app);

  IEclipseContext windowContext = window.getContext();

  windowContext.set(ISaveHandler.class, new SaveHandler());
```

Comment: Where exactly do i have to install the ISaveHandler? I tried `IApplicationContext`, but could not find any possiblity to set the handler. I Also tried `IEclipseContext#set(Class<T> clazz, T value)` , but to no avail.

Comment: It normally goes in the IEclipseContext for the main window and you can install it in the app startup complete event handler - see updated answer.

Comment: I am unable to catch the startup event, but I tried to set the ISaveHandler inside `@ProcessAdditions
 void processAdditions(final IEclipseContext workbenchContext) {}` in my LifeCycleManager. This method is called but still has no effect when i close the Part.

Comment: Have you made the part dirty? This all works fine for me.

Comment: Doing the call in @ProcessAdditions is too early, Eclipse sets a default save handler after that overriding yours. Note that `Event` in the app startup complete is `org.osgi.service.event.Event` other event classes will not work.